# How to find scss source address file in inspect element?

Tags: sass

I have plenty of scss file in my MVC project.All of them imported to a single scss file then compile to a MainStyle.css. Inspect element just show css line and css file name.
Now when I want to change any style its not possible to find that scss file name in inspect element.
In addition show original sources in explorer not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable source mapping when compiling from scss to css. You can check this article on that: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-source-maps-debug-sass-chrome/

Quick fix: You can go to the css line and copy the classname. Do a global search of wherever the classname is used. You should see the scss file along with what you're looking for

Comment: Glad I could help :)